# Accessing two databases

Tags: database, wp-config

I have two databases on my server, and wanted to know is there a way to access both databases from wordpress?  My thought is adding the second set of credentials to the `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily set up another `$wpdb` object to access your other database.

```
$mydb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
var_dump($mydb);
```

That, of course, uses the default connection credentials but if you defined different constants and used those, is should work just fine.

If this other database is not a WordPress database, you won't have some of the functionality offered by the `wpdb` class but the basics should work if you write the SQL.