# Storing Form data in a different database

Tags: plugins, multisite, database, forms, multisite-user-management

I have two wordpress websites and I want to store the data submitted by the forms in a centralized database in order to better manage the information.

Is there a way I can store form data in a different database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$wpdb` to access any database you have access to (credentials for)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100136/21376) so one site or the other could access its partner's database or both could access a third database. It shouldn't be hard but you will need to write most of the `SQL` to do it.

If you are in a position to refactor this, you could consider having both sites share the same database, [via distinct database prefixes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#table_prefix), and then save to custom table instead of bothering with access to multiple databases.

Your question is not really specific enough to allow for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am just trying to figure out how I can go about solving this problem.